# Chartjs chart with only one axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js3

Chartjs one line chart without grid, axis and tick labels.

[image]

I want to draw chart something like above.

I don't want axes labels, tick labels and grid lines, only one line which will progress on the right as data (X values) added to the chart. I want to display labels on the dots added to the chart. Can we have only one axis (X) in the chart?

I did try below:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lxya0u98/2/

My data set is as below:

```
{
  data: [{x:1, y:0}, {x:2, y:0}, {x:3, y:0}],
  showLine: true,  
  borderWidth: 1.5,
  borderColor: "blue",
  pointBackgroundColor: "blue",
  pointBorderColor: "blue",
  pointRadius: 5,
}
```

Comment: Yes you can simply hide/remove any elements you don't want.

Comment: not exactly one line chart, but give [SparkLine a look](https://github.com/fnando/sparkline), might interest you...

Comment: I am not able to remove or hide ticks and labels I dd try xAxes: {
        display: true,
    }, yAxes: {
        display: false,
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define options `ticks.display: false` together with `gridLines.display: false` on both axes, it should work fine.

Please take a look at below sample code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: "#0168FF",
      borderColor: "#0168FF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,      
      lineTension: 0,
      pointBorderColor: "blue",
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHoverRadius: 4,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        align: 'top',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return context.dataIndex + 1;
        }
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        right: 10
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{        
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="30"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can we avoid using a plugin for the labels and use something that is provided by chartjs?

Comment: As far as I know, Chart.js has no inbuilt feature for drawing value labels. You can use its Plugin Core API and programmatically draw the labels directly on the canvas.

Comment: Basically, I want to display dots denoting sections, using the code I always get a dot at the end which is actually a data set endpoint. Please refer updated image in the question.

Comment: @User7723337: You really shouldn't change the original question after you got an acceptable answer for it. It's recommended to simply post a new question for the new issue.

Comment: The plugin "chartjs-plugin-datalabels" is not working with Chart.js version 3.0.0-beta.7. Although the plugin mentions support for 2.7 and above, we get errors. We get errors when we try to load this plugin. Is there another way to have these labels in Chart.js 3.x version?

Comment: @User7723337: I posted a new answer that illustrates how to draw data labels with Chart.js v3.x.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comment from [User7723337](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314247/user7723337), the plugin `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` doesn't work with Chart.js version 3.0.0-beta.7.

As an alternative, you can draw the data labels directly on the `canvas` using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a number of hooks that can be used to perform custom code. In your case, you could use the `afterDraw` hook together with [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

> Note that I linked [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) with the Chart.js v2.x documentation because I couldn't find a corresponding section for v3.x. Apparently however, this is still also working with v3.x.

Please take a look at below code that uses Chart.js version 3.0.0-beta.7.

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "line",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y'];      
      chart.data.labels.forEach((l, i) => {
        var x = xAxis.getPixelForTick(i);
        var y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(0);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.font = '12px Arial';
        ctx.fillText(l, x, y - 14);
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      backgroundColor: "#0168FF",
      borderColor: "#0168FF",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      lineTension: 0,
      pointBorderColor: "blue",
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointHoverRadius: 4,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 10
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },    
    scales: {
      y: {
        display: false,
      },
      x: {
        display: false,
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.0-beta.7/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="30"></canvas>
```